# Melt list of identical dataframes to one dataframe in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, reshape2, melt

I have a **list** `waterlevels` of nine identical dataframes containing information about piezometers K01 to K09. Each of these dataframes contains 96860 rows, all of them having 13 variables, except for one having 21 variables (the extra columns in these one are not important).

```
$K01
           dateandtime seconds pressure_kPa temperature_.C baropressure_kpa barocompensation_kpa waterlevel_cm lengthcables_cm
1  2019-11-05 00:00:00       0      111.482         13.261           98.854               12.628      128.7697             490
2  2019-11-05 00:15:00     900      111.506         13.261           98.883               12.623      128.7188             490
3  2019-11-05 00:30:00    1800      111.511         13.261           98.872               12.639      128.8819             490
4  2019-11-05 00:45:00    2700      111.544         13.261           98.898               12.646      128.9533             490
5  2019-11-05 01:00:00    3600      111.536         13.313           98.913               12.623      128.7188             490
```

I want to melt this list to one dataframe containing only **one variable `barocompensation_kpa`** and the `dateandtime` variable using following code:

`waterlevels_all <- melt(waterlevels, id.vars=c("dateandtime", "barocompensation_kpa"))`

But then the resulting dataframe `waterlevels_all` has 10364020 observations, while only this df only should have 871740 rows (9*96860). So it has to have 3 variables: `dateandtime`,  `barocompensation_kpa` and `L1` being the name of corresponding dataframe (= name of the piezometer - K01 to K09).

```
> head(waterlevels_all)
        dateandtime barocompensation_kpa variable value  L1
1 2019-11-05 00:00:00         17.55336  seconds     0 K01
2 2019-11-05 00:15:00         17.55489  seconds   900 K01
3 2019-11-05 00:30:00         17.55703  seconds  1800 K01
4 2019-11-05 00:45:00         17.55347  seconds  2700 K01
5 2019-11-05 01:00:00         17.55540  seconds  3600 K01
6 2019-11-05 01:15:00         17.56050  seconds  4500 K01
```

How is this possible? How do I get the right dataframe?

Comment: Perhaps you want to `rbind` the list elements and then do `melt` once? i.e. `bind_rows(waterlevels, .id = 'kgrp') %>% melt(id.vars=c("kgrp", "dateandtime", "barocompensation_kpa"))`

Comment: @akrun No it didn't work. The resulting df obtains 16563060 rows...

Comment: When you apply the `melt` code on a single dataset, are you getting correct number of rows?

Comment: @akrun If I melt the dataframe K01, then I get 1065460 rows. But I totally do not understand why this results in so many observations...

Comment: It is because you are replicating by the number of columns length other than the id column

Comment: @akrun Thanks for the explanation. Do you have another solution?

Comment: If it is to subset you can use `library(purrr);imap_dfr(waterlevels, ~ .x %>% select(dateandtime, barocompensation_kpa) %>% mutate(L1 = .y))` or `map_dfr(waterlevels, ~ .x %>% select(dateandtime, barocompensation_kpa), .id = "L1")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some options with `tidyverse` - Loop over the `list` with `imap`, `select` the columns of interest and create the new column 'L1' with the list element name (`.y`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
imap_dfr(waterlevels, ~ .x %>% 
   select(dateandtime, barocompensation_kpa) %>%
   mutate(L1 = .y))
```

Or with `map`, just `select` the columns and create the new column with `.id` (`_dfr` returns a single dataset by rbinding the list elements)

```
map_dfr(waterlevels, ~ .x %>% 
     select(dateandtime, barocompensation_kpa), .id = "L1")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `lapply` with a subsequent `Map` and `rbind`.

```
lapply(lst, subset, select=c('dateandtime', 'barocompensation_kpa')) |>
  Map(f=`[<-`, 'L1', value=names(lst)) |>
  # c(make.row.names=FALSE) |>  ## optional, to reset row names
  do.call(what=rbind)
#       dateandtime barocompensation_kpa  L1
# K01.1           0                    0 K01
# K01.2           0                    0 K01
# K01.3           0                    0 K01
# K02.1           0                    0 K02
# K02.2           0                    0 K02
# K02.3           0                    0 K02
# K03.1           0                    0 K03
# K03.2           0                    0 K03
# K03.3           0                    0 K03
```

---

*Data:*

```
lst <- list(K01 = structure(list(dateandtime = c(0, 0, 0), seconds = c(0, 
0, 0), pressure_kPa = c(0, 0, 0), temperature_.C = c(0, 0, 0), 
    baropressure_kpa = c(0, 0, 0), barocompensation_kpa = c(0, 
    0, 0), waterlevel_cm = c(0, 0, 0), lengthcables_cm = c(0, 
    0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame"), K02 = structure(list(
    dateandtime = c(0, 0, 0), seconds = c(0, 0, 0), pressure_kPa = c(0, 
    0, 0), temperature_.C = c(0, 0, 0), baropressure_kpa = c(0, 
    0, 0), barocompensation_kpa = c(0, 0, 0), waterlevel_cm = c(0, 
    0, 0), lengthcables_cm = c(0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = "data.frame"), K03 = structure(list(dateandtime = c(0, 
0, 0), seconds = c(0, 0, 0), pressure_kPa = c(0, 0, 0), temperature_.C = c(0, 
0, 0), baropressure_kpa = c(0, 0, 0), barocompensation_kpa = c(0, 
0, 0), waterlevel_cm = c(0, 0, 0), lengthcables_cm = c(0, 0, 
0), X9 = c(0, 0, 0), X10 = c(0, 0, 0), X11 = c(0, 0, 0), X12 = c(0, 
0, 0), X13 = c(0, 0, 0), X14 = c(0, 0, 0), X15 = c(0, 0, 0), 
    X16 = c(0, 0, 0), X17 = c(0, 0, 0), X18 = c(0, 0, 0), X19 = c(0, 
    0, 0), X20 = c(0, 0, 0), X21 = c(0, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)))
```